# Background Image not showing where negative top-margin set in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image

I have a scrolling image section (the images are background images not ing tags) that uses top-margin: -28px; to move it below a portion of the header on a site I'm making. It's displaying perfectly on Safari, Chrome etc but on Firefox the top 28px of the image are not displaying.

Any ideas why? I have no idea and it's driving me nuts.

The site is here http://www.chelt.org.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your negative margin is applied to the children `<div>` tags of `#slides`.

Since you have `overflow: hidden;` applied to `#slides`, the portion that is pushed outside of the `#slides` div is hidden.

The solution:

1. Remove the `margin-top` from `#feature`
2. Add `top: -28px;` to `#slides`

I should also point out that assigning an Id of `#feature` to all of your slides is not valid.  Ids need to be unique, meaning you cannot have more than one of the same Id.  You should make it `#feature-1`, `#feature-2`.... if you must assign an Id to the slides.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Use `.top` instead:

```
.slides{
    top: -28px;
}
```

Also remove the negative margin from

```
#feature {
    margin-top: -28px; <-- Remove
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In other news, you have `#feature` appearing more than once in the markup. An ID should only appear once. If you need to use this on more than one element it should be a class.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed perfectly.

Also fixed the Id error, thanks for the heads up.